# Does 'feelings of solitude' sound good or correct?

Tags: vocabulary, collocations

I always see/read sentences like :

'..and this can cause you to have *feelings of loneliness*.'

or

'but it’s hard to cope when *feelings of worthlessness and loneliness* persist.'

So I wonder if it will still sound correct to say *feelings of solitude* also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words "loneliness" and "worthlessness" are pretty much always emotions or mental states, so they are appropriate objects for "feelings of". The word "solitude" on the othe hand, most often means the actual fact of being alone. However it can also be used to describe the metal state resulting from being alone, and in that sense could be used with "feelings of".

"feelings of solitude" seems a bit odd, i think because of the primary meaning of "solitude" not being a feelign or mental state. But I don't see anything actually wrong with it.

Comment: I too felt that it would sound a little bit odd but I just couldn't put my hands on the reason why. But now ,thanks to you, you explained it perfectly.                            I think 'feelings of isolation' would sound better ,as it can be an emotion somewho, even though it will have a slightly different meaning due to the little difference between isolation and solitude.

Comment: @Manar I don't think '[put my hands on](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+my+hands+on)' has the meaning of 'get my head around', so maybe it's just an expression from your native language?

Comment: @Michael You're right. It's from my native language :)